# cisco commands to kickout users

Tags: cisco, router, command

I need a cisco router commands to end a user session at console port.

The commands will be issued to the router using another software periodically.

The purpose is to end a user session connected to the console port of the router.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it, I believe:

```
> clear line <TTY_number>
```